# NSOpenPanel restrict already selected file

Tags: objective-c, macos, cocoa, nsopenpanel

I have added NSOpenPanel for selecting folders. But I want achieve following cases:
1. Restrict user to select already selected folders.
2. Restrict user to select sub folders if parent folder already selected.

Or if above cases are not possible then how can check whether parent folder of current selected folder is already selected or not?

```
//Panel related code
    aPanel = [NSOpenPanel openPanel];
    [aPanel setMessage:@"Choose folders"];
    [aPanel setPrompt:@"Select"];
    [aPanel setNameFieldLabel:@"Location"];
    [aPanel setAllowsMultipleSelection:YES];
    [aPanel setCanChooseDirectories:YES];
    [aPanel setDirectoryURL:[NSURL fileURLWithPath:NSHomeDirectory()]];
    [aPanel setDelegate:self];
    dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^
    {
        [aPanel beginSheetModalForWindow:self.view.window completionHandler:^(NSInteger result)
        {
            if (result == NSFileHandlingPanelOKButton)
            {
                for (NSURL *folderPath in [aPanel URLs])
                {
                    [files addObject:[folderPath path]];
                }
            }
        }];
    });

//Filter method handle
    - (BOOL)panel:(id)sender shouldEnableURL:(NSURL *)url {
        BOOL result = YES;
        for (NSString *urlPath in files) {
            result  = result && ( [url.path hasPrefix:urlPath] ||  [urlPath isEqualTo:url.path] ? NO : YES);
        }
        return result;
    }
```

Here files is old selected folder list having string type paths

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Have you added `NSLog()` calls, or used the debugger, to see what is going on? Think again about the conditions under which you need `shouldEnableURL` to return `YES`/`NO`. For example consider:

- I think you want to return `YES` if *any* of the paths in `files` and the URL being checked meet some condition. *Any* suggests *or* (`||`) yet your logic uses *and* (`&&`). Also *any* suggests you can return directly within the loop as once your condition is met with one path from `files` there is no need to test the others.
- Use of the ternary conditional operator `? :`

  - What is the precedence of this compared to `||`, i.e. does your expression evaluate as `(a || b) ? NO : YES` or as `a || (b ? NO : YES)`?
  - Don't write `e ? NO : YES`, instead use the Boolean *not* operator as in `!e`

By considering the above and using `NSLog()`/the debugger you should quickly be able to determine the logic required to return the Boolean value you need (whatever it is).

HTH

Answer (score 0):

NSOpenSavePanelDelegate's -panel:shouldEnableURL: method allows you to disable URLs so they can not be selected:

https://developer.apple.com/documentation/appkit/nsopensavepaneldelegate/1535200-panel?language=objc

Comment: I have already try this method but failed to achieve above two cases

Comment: I'm not going to try to analyse whether that code is actually doing what you want it to do but the obvious diagnostic test is to return `NO` from `-shouldEnableURL:` regardless.  Then, if everything is greyed out, you know that the mechanism basically works and you can track down the bug in your own code.